# Spring mvc - How can I get mapping info in intercetor

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, interceptor

Spring mvc - How can I get mapping info in interceptor?

ex - When user request **/user/12345** url, I want to get **/user/{id}** string in interceptor.
How can i do?

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    String mappingUri = someMethod(); // get "/post/{id}"; but not /post/12345

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code return ["/user/{id}"]

```
public static List<String> getMappingInfo(HandlerMethod method) {
        String prefixs[] = method.getBean().getClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value();
        if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(prefixs))
            prefixs = new String[] { "" };

        String mappings[] = method.getMethod().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value();

        List<String> info = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String prefix : prefixs) {
            for (String mapping : mappings) {
                info.add(prefix + "/" + mapping);
            }
        }

        return info;
    }
```

Comment: Were you trying to get the mapping or the value bound to the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't recommend doing this. The name of the identifier for the path element should only be known to the controller handler method. Your interceptor has no business knowing about it. What's more, if this logic only applies to that mapping, you might as well put it inside the handler method and use `@PathVariable`.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> uriTemplateVars = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
    return true;
}
```

You can now use any key, like `"id"` to retrieve a path element from `uriTemplateVars`.

Comment: When I Request "/user/12345", This result is "{ids=12345}"

Comment: @한국인 `uriTemplateVars` is a `Map`. Extract the entry you want from it. `uriTemplateVars.get("ids")`